# Why does a WPF Popup close when its background area is clicked?

Tags: .net, wpf, popup, focus

I have a WPF `Popup` control that contains some editing controls (list boxes, text boxes, check boxes) laid out with quite a bit of whitespace.

`Popup.StaysOpen` is set to `False`, which is required.  If the user clicks elsewhere in the application, the editing operation should be considered aborted and the popup should close.

Unfortunately the popup also closes whenever the user clicks within the background region of the popup (the space between the edit controls).

I've tried setting the popup to be `Focusable`.  I've also tried setting the popup's child (a `Border`) to be focusable.  No luck on either front.

Furthermore, the mouse event seems to tunnel through the popup.  Whatever element is underneath the popup when I click it becomes focused.  This is despite both the `Popup` and the `Border` (into which I'm clicking) having both `IsHitTestVisible` and `Focusable` set to `true`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the end, I found that the following worked.  Given...

```
<Popup x:Name="_popup"
       StaysOpen="False"
       PopupAnimation="Slide"
       AllowsTransparency="True">
```

...I used this code in the constructor after calling `InitializeComponent`...

```
// Ensure that any mouse event that gets through to the
// popup is considered handled, otherwise the popup would close
_popup.MouseDown += (s, e) => e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: Great solution! I was even able to do it with a control defined on Generic.xaml, by using EventToCommand, passing the EventArgs to the command, and then setting Handled=True. Thanks!

Comment: Another way to sneak the even handler into a tricky spot is to derive an `ArmouredPopup` class that derives from `Popup`.  It can override `OnMouseDown`.  I regard this a bug in the default popup class.

Comment: I would tend to say this isn't a great solution, not because what you've provided is bad (it's actually good), but because developers shouldn't have to do this. I've been toying around with this for ages and it looks as if the click event is propagated to another event handler which in turn closes the popup again. There's probably a MS Connect issue already open for it so let's hope the MS team issue a fix. (@AdrianRatnapala agreed)

Answer (score 7):

It does seem odd that it would ignore Focusable on the Popup and Border.  I was able to fix your problem by changing StaysOpen in a trigger when the mouse is over the Border:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ToggleButton x:Name="btnPop" Content="Pop!" Width="100" Height="50"/>
    <Popup Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnPop}" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btnPop}">
        <Popup.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                <Setter Property="StaysOpen" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=brd}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="StaysOpen" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Popup.Style>
        <Border x:Name="brd" Background="White" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Margin="10"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some text is here." Margin="10"/>
                <TextBox Margin="10"/>
            </StackPanel>            
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Actually, this works for me. Just one thing that's important to note, @RobertMacnee, is that you should make sure you don't set the `StaysOpen` property on the Popup element itself, it should be left to the style setter and trigger entirely otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you have your Popup nested in a ToggleButton or other kind of Button? Then stopping the routed event at Popup level would be logical to get working.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is you have some transparency issues going on. Try setting a background brush on the popup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The border control fills the entire region of the popup and has a solid brush set

Answer (score -1):

you can set **StayOpen**=true,and set a timer,in the Popup's MouseLeave event timer.Start(),such as after 3 seconds,close this popup,in the MouseEnter event,timer.Stop().
It will works.