# Popups in XBAP stop receiving anything but mouse events after losing focus?

Tags: wpf, popup, focus, xbap

I have a `Popup` control in my XBAP, and whenever the popup control is open and it loses focus (such as an alert box, a breakpoint, switching to another application in Windows, switching to another Tab in my web browser, etc), the Popup no longer responds to anything but Mouse events.

I cannot:

- Select a TextBox with the Mouse
- Highlight Text in a TextBox with the Mouse
- Use the Tab key to change controls
- Select a ComboBox item using the Keyboard when I open it with the Mouse

I can:

- Change a ComboBox value with the Mouse
- Click a button with the Mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest thing to this problem I could find was http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/cd723315-187f-4d8b-a97d-6aac38a2ed1f

Programmer was losing focus to their popup and never able to get it back. According to a Microsoft Supporter. "it looks like you hit a known bug related to Popup in XBAP."

You can see if it's similar to your issue, but the problem was never solved. OP ended up adding a canvas to the main page and a usercontrol to replace the popup window.

---

If this in fact isn't some sort of unavoidable behaviour, and I were tackling this problem from scratch, I would check when your application regains focus and see whether your application is getting both the [keyboard and logical focus](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/eburke/archive/2009/03/18/why-is-focus-in-wpf-so-tricky-managing-and-understanding-focus-in-a-wpf-application.aspx), and that the focus scope is correct all the way down to the controls on your popup.

> In Logical focus, there is the notion of a “Focus Scope”, which is an application-defined boundary around a group of UIElements.  Each Focus Scope maintains its own “Focused Element” which can be different than the element that has Keyboard focus.

Comment: lol I should have known better than to use WPF Popups for anything. I actually have my own Popup UserControl that I usually use, but in this case I felt like trying out WPF's popup once again since it's been a while since I last tried it. Back to using my UserControl I guess....