# WPF popup doesn`t close on click

Tags: wpf, popup

**Update:**
Here is a link for a reproduction
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzalDCHAtuAPUk5vWF9PVUE2QzQ/view?usp=sharing

**Back to original question:**

I tried to find some answer here but haven`t found any.

I have a collection of items where on click of an item a popup is opened, and when clicked outside of the item the popup is closed. From some reason, when the popup is opened, when I click the same item again the popup is closed and reopened instead of staying closed.
Here are my pieces of code:

**Some clarification:**
I have two collections. One is sitting inside an ItemsControl and one is sitting inside a ListView. The MouseClickToCommandBehavior below sits on both the ItemsControl and the ListView. I use it to tell the Popup when to open and close. I also need the popup to close when I click outside of the item.
Currently when I click an item inside the ListView or the ItemsControl (when the popup for that item is already opened) the Popup reopens instead of closing.
This occurs because of the StaysOpen property set to "false" which is required for the popup to close when I click outside of the item.

**Back to original question:**

The popup

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding ShowCustomerCardOptionsPopup, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" StaysOpen="False"
       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=CUstomerCardGrid}"
       Placement="Right">
```

The behavior to open the popup (which is set on the ListView)

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:MouseClickToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding OpenPopupForCustomerCard}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CustomerCardsListView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The command action

```
private void OpenPopupForCustomerCardAction(ICustomerModel model)
{
    model.ShowCustomerCardOptionsPopup = !model.ShowCustomerCardOptionsPopup;
}
```

And the call stack when clicking on the same item

```
value: True
at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at POS.Models.CustomerModel.set_ShowCustomerCardOptionsPopup(Boolean value)
at POS.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel.OpenPopupForCustomerCardAction(ICustomerModel model)
at POS.InfraStructure.ActionCommand`1.Execute(Object parameter)
at POS.Views.Behaviors.MouseClickToCommandBehavior.AssociatedObject_MouseUp(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)

====================
value: False
at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at POS.Models.CustomerModel.set_ShowCustomerCardOptionsPopup(Boolean value)

====================
value: False
at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at POS.Models.CustomerModel.set_ShowCustomerCardOptionsPopup(Boolean value)

====================
value: True
at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at POS.Models.CustomerModel.set_ShowCustomerCardOptionsPopup(Boolean value)
at POS.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel.OpenPopupForCustomerCardAction(ICustomerModel model)
at POS.InfraStructure.ActionCommand`1.Execute(Object parameter)
at POS.Views.Behaviors.MouseClickToCommandBehavior.AssociatedObject_MouseUp(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

I would love to know why is the "false" value called twice
and how can I prevent either the false or second true from occurring (more
preferbly the false and still have the behavior of StaysOpen="False")

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicated with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619798/why-does-a-wpf-popup-close-when-its-background-area-is-clicked?rq=1

Comment: Already checked this. his problem is different from mine (At least this is how I see it)

Comment: @shahareldad I think the problem caused by mouse click event, beacause you re-switch the ShowCustomerCardOptionsPopup property each time you enter the OpenPopupForCustomerCardAction method. Try to use the item selection changed event instead of the mouse click, in this case the behavior will trigger the action only when the new selection will occure.

Comment: @Ilan The question is how else would I open and close the Popup when I click on the collection item.

Comment: @shahareldad can you specify this in your question? i can't understand the question I'm sorry?

Comment: @Ilan Added some clarifications in the question. I hope they made it more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem by opening or closing the Popup with a Button.

I needed to to disable `IsHitTestVisible` on the open / close Button while the Popup is open.

```
IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsOpen, ElementName=MyPopup, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"
```

Otherwise, the Popup closes as defined by `StaysOpen="False"` when clicking on the Button. And after that it is opened again as a result of the Button click.

With this simple converter (just for completeness):

```
public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !((bool)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !((bool)value);
    }
}
```