# Controlling the open and close of Popup from a Button click in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, popup

My requirement is to control the closing/opening of popup from a Button. In my below piece of code by clicking on button the popup opens up but it doesn't closes on the next click.

XAML

```
 <Button x:Name="Btn" Height="20" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="Show Popup"/>
                        <Button.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                             Storyboard.TargetName="Popup" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True" />
                                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Button.Triggers>
                    </Button>
                     <Popup x:Name="Popup" StaysOpen="False"  
        Height="100" Width="300" Background= "Yellow" 
    
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Btn}"></Popup>
```

**Note:** I am able to achieve the above case using a Toggle button, But my requirement is very specific to button only.

Comment: I am not aware how to alternate different animations, but you can have 2 buttons: one to open (visible) and another to close (hidden). In addition to changing `Popup.IsOpen` they need to change own and opposite button visibility.

Comment: I know I am late, but could https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149367/wpf-popup-doesnt-close-on-click be a solution to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without toggling i.e. `Button` alone can't do it. You are handling a control that has a state: opened and closed. You need to know the current state. To achieve this, add a flag to the hosting control (requires code-behind) or use the flag of the `Popup` (requires code-behind) or use the flag of the `ToggleButton` (no code-behind).

It doesn't make any sense to avoid the `ToggleButton`: it's a `Button` that additionally knows or has a state. It can handle `ICommand` or emit a `Click` event - it's a `Button`. It's exactly what you need.

You don't have to explicitly add a `TextBlock` to the `Content` of the `Button`. When assigning a string to `Button.Content`, the control will automatically create a `TextBlock` to show the string.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Button Click="TogglePopup_OnClick"
        Content="Show Popup" />
                
<Popup x:Name="Popup" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void TogglePopup_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  => this.Popup.IsOpen ^= true;
```