# Interact With Controls Inside a WPF Popup Without It Closing

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, controls

In my WPF application, I am trying to use a Popup control in several places instead of having to represent the controls in the MainWindow, which would be redundant and messy with my current layout. The following XAML shows my current Popup and its contents.

```
<Popup x:Name="MainPopup"
       StaysOpen="False"
       Placement="Center"
       PopupAnimation="Slide"
       AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Border BorderBrush="White"
        Background="White"
        BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid Background="White">
            <DataGrid>

            <!--Dummy Data -->

            </DataGrid>
            <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

The main issue is that any attempt to interact with the DataGrid or Button result in the Popup control closing. I've tried many different configurations of `StaysOpen`, `IsOpen`, `Focusable`,`AllowsTransparency`, and even set the backgrounds properties to actual colors.

Two things I found that *looked* promising (but did not yield any positive results) are listed below:

[Why does a WPF Popup close when its background area is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619798/why-does-a-wpf-popup-close-when-its-background-area-is-clicked)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/be1a55df-8008-4af5-b782-5a15f1bc146c/wpf-how-to-restrict-the-popup-from-closing-while-click-on-a-windows-forms-element?forum=wpf

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

---

### EDIT

To clarify, I am using the Popup control in a DataGrid cell editing template.
The app is basically a visual data entry app and the content in the MainWindow serves as the data input form. Here is a rough outline of the structure, along with an image of the actual Popup control.

- MainWindow

  - ItemsControl

    - DataGrid (ItemTemplate)

      - Popup (CellEditingTemplate)

**Popup Example:**
[image: Popup]

So, when I scroll to an item that I want to see the popup for, I double-click on that cell, thus enabling the Popup. So any single Popup is sort of "hosted" within a single DataGrid cell. Perhaps this is related to the issue?

Comment: Did you tried the suggested solutions provided by your link? The one handling the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` may help. Anyway, when you need a lot of workarounds to make a control works the way you want, you may consider changing the control ^^.

Comment: Indeed, I did. After doing “e.Handled = true” in all the mouse events of the Popup control, the Popup no longer disappeared, but intercepted all the mouse input and disallowed any of the nested controls from being manipulated.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code? I copy/paste your code with the empty `DataGrid` an added a `MainPopup.IsOpen = true;` into a `Button.Click` and I can interact with the Popup's button without problem.

Comment: Absolutely, I am glad to provide more if it helps find a solution. Original post was updated with more info. Thank you, @P.Manthe! =)

Comment: I added the `Popup` into `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate`/`DataTemplate`/`Grid` => `Popup` and it works well. I can interact with the button belonging to the `Popup`. The only difference is that I added `IsOpen=True` into the XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though my problem was related to the fact that I was actually using a separate UserControl to host my Popup. When placing it *directly* into my CellEditingTemplate DataTemplate, it worked. So while I'm not sure how to fix the initial issue, my workaround was to create all the Popup content inside its own DataTemplate (instead of a UserControl), which seems to mostly do the trick.